# Why instagram shows 'New registrations not supported anymore'

Tags: api, instagram

How to create an app in instagarm ?
 I redirected to [register](https://www.instagram.com/developer/clients/register/) And it shows `New registrations not supported anymore`

Comment: Please determine your programming language?

Comment: angular 2 with typescript

Answer (score 1):

The [legacy Instagram API](https://www.instagram.com/developer/) will be deprecated in March 2020.

You should either migrate to the [Instagram Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/) or the new [Instagram Basic Display API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api), which currently only allows you to fetch media from your Instagram account.

[Instagram Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/) is more advanced and allows you to fetch hashtagged posts and much more, but it requires a Facebook connection to fetch the Instagram Business or Creator accounts that you manage.

Answer (score 0):

On the Instagram [developer page](https://www.instagram.com/developer/) it reads:

> UPDATE: Starting October 15, 2019, new client registration and permission review on >Instagram API platform are discontinued in favor of the [Instagram Basic Display API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/).